# How and when is ray.method(num_return_values) used?

Tags: python, methods, ray

The ray tutorial explains, that for having a method on an object, which returns multiple object_ids one can use the @ray.method() decorator [see here](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actors.html#actor-methods). But in the example 'Learning to play Pong' the method *compute gradient* actually has two return values, which are called as object_ids later, but it is not coded as ray.method with the respective decorator[see here](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_pong_example.html#parallelizing-gradients). I would like to understand what the use of ray.method is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return a tuple when fetching the object.

The equivalent paradigm in Python is:

```
def test():
    return 1, 2

a = test()
assert a == (1, 2)
```